# Embed 3D model viewer

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, embed

I'm trying to implement [this](http://www.radiatedpixel.com/wordpress/2013/03/27/webgl-3d-model-viewer-using-three-js/) 3D model viewer, however I want to embed it into an already set div instead of making a new one as this does. So I've edited the code like so but it hasn't worked. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script>
    // This is where our model viewer code goes.
    var container;
    var camera, scene, renderer;
    var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

    var windowHalfX = document.getElementById('viewer').clientHeight / 2;
    var windowHalfY = document.getElementById('viewer').clientHeight / 2;

    init();
    animate();

    // Initialize
    function init() {
      // This <div> will host the canvas for our scene.
      container = document.getElementById( 'viewer' );
      //document.body.appendChild( container );

      // You can adjust the cameras distance and set the FOV to something
      // different than 45°. The last two values set the clippling plane.
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
      camera.position.z = 100;

      // These variables set the camera behaviour and sensitivity.
      controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
      controls.rotateSpeed = 5.0;
      controls.zoomSpeed = 5;
      controls.panSpeed = 2;
      controls.noZoom = false;
      controls.noPan = false;
      controls.staticMoving = true;
      controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;

      // This is the scene we will add all objects to.
      scene = new THREE.Scene();

      // You can set the color of the ambient light to any value.
      // I have chose a completely white light because I want to paint
      // all the shading into my texture. You propably want something darker.
      var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff );
      scene.add( ambient );

      // Uncomment these lines to create a simple directional light.
      // var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
      // directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 ).normalize();
      // scene.add( directionalLight );

      // Texture Loading
      var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
      manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {
        console.log( item, loaded, total );
      };
      var texture = new THREE.Texture();
      var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader( manager );

      // You can set the texture properties in this function. 
      // The string has to be the path to your texture file.

      loader.load( 'img/sickletexture.png', function ( image ) {
        texture.image = image;
        texture.needsUpdate = true;
        // I wanted a nearest neighbour filtering for my low-poly character,
        // so that every pixel is crips and sharp. You can delete this lines
        // if have a larger texture and want a smooth linear filter.
        texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
        texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestMipMapLinearFilter;
      } );

      // OBJ Loading
      var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );

      // As soon as the OBJ has been loaded this function looks for a mesh
      // inside the data and applies the texture to it.
      loader.load( 'obj/sickle.obj', function ( event ) {
        var object = event;
        object.traverse( function ( child ) {
          if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            child.material.map = texture;
          }
        } );

        // My initial model was too small, so I scaled it upwards.
        object.scale = new THREE.Vector3( 2, 2, 2 );

        // You can change the position of the object, so that it is not
        // centered in the view and leaves some space for overlay text.
        object.position.y -= 2.5;
        scene.add( object );
      });

      // We set the renderer to the size of the window and
      // append a canvas to our HTML page.
      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize( document.getElementById('viewer').innerWidth, document.getElementById('viewer').innerHeight );
      container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    }

    // The Loop 
    function animate() {
      // This function calls itself on every frame. You can for example change
      // the objects rotation on every call to create a turntable animation.
      requestAnimationFrame( animate );

      // On every frame we need to calculate the new camera position
      // and have it look exactly at the center of our scene.
      controls.update();
      camera.lookAt(scene.position);
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

  </script>
```

Comment: init may be called before the page has loaded and there is no viewer div on the page yet. You might need to put you initilisation in method called by the document onLoad event. `<body onload="init()">`. This will mean init is called once the page is fully loaded and the viewer div has been created.

Comment: First thing to try is to see if the obj loader example works. If you have downloaded the zip and unpacked as `three` in your base web directory then try `http:localhost//three/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html`. This should work out of the box. If not there is a problem with your setup. It looks like it only runs via a webserver so it will not work with the `file:` protocol.

Comment: @Salixalba it works perfectly in its own page, but im trying to embed it in a div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a rather easy solution, I'm surprised I did not find it earlier.

Create the 3D in a seperate html document (using the original script, not the edited one in the OP), then in the div `<embed src="3d.html"></embed>`

Comment: Yes works nicely. It also overcomes a problem I had with three taking over the mouse controls preventing the page from scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to get things to work myself and this code works for me with the latest version (66) of three. Its a little different to you example as I am using a vrml model rather than an obj and I handle the material differently. But it does run fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - loaders - vrml loader</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            threewindow {
                border: 1px solid black;
                }
        </style>

        <script src="../three.js/build/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../three.js/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
        <script src="../three.js/examples/js/loaders/VRMLLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="../three.js/examples/js/Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="../three.js/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
            var container, stats;
            var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
            var cross;

            function init() {
                alert("init");
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 1e10 );
                camera.position.z = 6;

                controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
                controls.rotateSpeed = 5.0;
                controls.zoomSpeed = 5;
                controls.panSpeed = 2;
                controls.noZoom = false;
                controls.noPan = false;
                controls.staticMoving = true;
                controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.add( camera );

                var sphereMaterial =
                      new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(
                        {
                          color: 0xCC0000
                        });

                // light

                var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
                dirLight.position.set( 200, 200, 1000 ).normalize();

                camera.add( dirLight );
                camera.add( dirLight.target );

                var loader = new THREE.VRMLLoader();
                loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
                    var object = event.content; 
                    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                          if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                            //child.material.map = texture;
                            //child.material = sphereMaterial;
                            child.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
                          }
                       } );

                    scene.add(object);

                } );
//              loader.load( "models/vrml/house.wrl" );
                loader.load( "cayley.wrl" );

                // renderer

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                renderer.setSize(200, 200);
                document.getElementById("threewindow").appendChild(renderer.domElement);
//              container = document.createElement( 'div' );
//              document.body.appendChild( container );
//              container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

//              stats = new Stats();
//              stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
//              stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
//              container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

                animate();
            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                controls.handleResize();

            }

            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                controls.update();
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
                //stats.update();
            }

        </script>

    </head>

    <body onload="init()">

    <h1>Cubic surfaces</h1>
    <p>All the surfaces defined by cubics equations.</p>
    <ul><li><a href="parade/Cubics.php">Singularities of cubic surfaces</a>.</li>
    <li>A <a href="parade/index.html">pictorial introduction</a> to singularity theory.</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="threewindow"></div>


    </body>
</html>
```